# PCRE regex remove string

Tags: regex, perl, sed, pcre

I have following string `sip:123456789@example.com:5065`

I want to output like following, so in short i want to remove anything between `:` and `@`

`sip:example.com:5065`

How do i use `PCRE` regex to remove that string?

Comment: Are you aware that `sed` doesn't support PCRE?

Comment: @anubhava For PCRE 
there is [`Super-sed`](https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Super-sed). `:)`

Comment: Thanks @jaypal: Yes I was aware of `ssed` but haven't tried it on OSX.

Comment: Regex don't remove; they define a set of strings. PCRE regex isn't enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed 's/:[^@]*@/:/' input > output
```

Comment: Or just `s/[^:@]*@//`

Answer (score 0):

Or this `sed`

```
sed s/[^:]*@//
```

```
echo "sip:123456789@example.com:5065" | sed s/[^:]*@//
sip:example.com:5065
```